# Filter a list of URLs from a list of domain names using Bash

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have a list of articles and would like to filter the list so that the new list of articles only contain articles from a set number of domains.

Right now, I have a list of articles (~500) as well as a list of domains (~3,000).

How do I remove articles from the list of articles that are not in my list of domains?

Both are text files, how do I do it on Bash?

I have a feeling you'll have to take the list of articles, get their domain names, put those two things in an array, and then compare the domain names in the array with the domain names in the list and, if they match, keep them. If not, remove the item and go to the next one.

this is what I have so far:

```
readarray a < ./articles
#I know "${b[@]}" is incorrect but idk how to write what I'm trying to do.
awk -F/ '{print $3}' "${a[@]}" > "${b[@]}" 
echo "${b[@]}"
# I'm lost after this
```

Here are the inputs:

articles.txt:

```
http://www.cbsnews.com/videos/white-house-knows-options-are-limited-in-ukraine/&amp;ct=ga&amp;cd=CAIyAA&amp;usg=AFQjCNFeY2uVQrvvDAMHeT-0nK2ZLNH7-g
http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/03/01/ukraine-russia-crimea_n_4879935.html&amp;ct=ga&amp;cd=CAIyAA&amp;usg=AFQjCNFH7GY3B6swce3qiK49xGt-CwDvMA
http://www.nybooks.com/blogs/nyrblog/2014/mar/01/ukraine-haze-propaganda/&amp;ct=ga&amp;cd=CAIyAA&amp;usg=AFQjCNFCcWadUJiAzaxg3OSO67gVIPVxww
http://ktla.com/2014/03/01/russian-upper-house-approves-use-of-military-force-in-ukraine-as-protests-continue/&amp;ct=ga&amp;cd=CAIyAA&amp;usg=AFQjCNGTkxvvAo1zSYLlA5ET54OcBsS-PA
http://deadlinelive.info/2014/03/01/you-quit-falling-for-the-war-on-terror-ukraine-coup-spawns-cold-war-redux-2014/&amp;ct=ga&amp;cd=CAIyAA&amp;usg=AFQjCNE3Fa_h7xoESBkcOzXVZCQnfBfxNA
http://www.ctvnews.ca/world/russian-parliament-oks-putin-s-request-to-use-military-force-in-ukraine-1.1709506&amp;ct=ga&amp;cd=CAIyAA&amp;usg=AFQjCNGnGeo4LWoLF5Qbq2UvL58ymlNFkA
http://www.vanguardngr.com/2014/03/un-security-council-hold-emergency-talks-ukraine/&amp;ct=ga&amp;cd=CAIyAA&amp;usg=AFQjCNFN7YRo037au4RfxSQoeVUCcL9hhA
http://www.reddit.com/r/AdviceAnimals/comments/1z82rt/russian_troops_cross_the_border_in_ukraine/&amp;ct=ga&amp;cd=CAIyAA&amp;usg=AFQjCNFHkmelnoRy2TCW-eYDpIt_t-N1iA
http://criticallegalthinking.com/2014/03/01/knot-politics-thoughts-ukraine-protest/&amp;ct=ga&amp;cd=CAIyAA&amp;usg=AFQjCNFLMuZzbuvzpLf7a9U8MtbhCE5lJQ
http://nypost.com/2014/03/01/russia-parliament-approves-military-action-in-ukraine/&amp;ct=ga&amp;cd=CAIyAA&amp;usg=AFQjCNFpdyelZDEMUk39LmfC1tTDcQ6_FA
```

domains.txt:

```
cbsnews.com
huffingtonpost.com
```

Comment: Could you please add some representative inputs for both the articles and domains to your question?

Comment: added the two text files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for example if your list of articles is in a file `articles`and looks like

```
... article1 ........ 1.domain.com .......
... article2 ........ 1.domain.com .......
... article3 ........ 2.domain.com .......
... article3 ........ 3.domain.com .......
... article4 ........ 4.domain.com .......
```

and your domain list is also in a file `domains` and looks like

```
1.domain.com 
2.domain.com 
4.domain.com
```

(if it's not, hopefully you can extract the domains and put them into a file like above)
then

```
grep -f domains articles > my_wish_list
```

will give you only articles in specified in the file domains

Comment: My bad, the articles are URLs of articles. I've clarified it now in the OP.

Comment: and? for your article and domain lists the pointed solution gives 2 articles

Answer (score 0):

If the list is never likely to exceed these numbers then a simple grep one-liner would work:

```
for mydomain in `cat domains.txt`;do cat articles.txt |grep $mydomain >> goodarticles.txt;done
```